# system architecture or software architecture

Tags: computer-architecture, design-patterns

I was trying to get started with a small project but I quickly realized I had to do more research on the subject.

Suppose, when creating a site, in production, there's a certain structure how the backend and front end are maintained for scalability. Suppose, you're node application is containerized, deployed inside a EKS environment. How, the backend front end and other stuff like ETL, CI/CD deployment are all arranged, and there's a flow of how these components interact.  And there's also something in the background stuff, that's not here visible apparantly, which would be the devops side(?) .

I was wondering I should take a course on how to design this, but, am not quite sure which field of computer science is this. Also, courses like [system design and  architecture](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/software-design-architecture#courses) tend to be more abstract, but, I wanted design specifically geared towards web dev if possible. What's this specific field that deals with this. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

EDITED: The goal would be to create a more sophisticated version of [this](https://litslink.com/blog/web-application-architecture)

Comment: Did you get enough information to answer your own question here? Very curious what you were able to find.

Comment: @montrealist , not really, I searched for course, and there's just generality of some theory of basic principles. There's nothing out there, that even demostrates a complete commercial production pipeline. Please let me know if you find any. Some industry people that have experience tell me, they start out like this and eventually working with experienced people gain more knowledge, but, that was about it... I know it's impossible to get all generality, but, at least a course from solution architecting to deploying fully scalable commercial application would be great as a complete reference.